# Rails: Social sharing image fails to display - image hosted on Amazon AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having an issue with a share photo showing up blank on Facebook.

The app that I'm using can be found here:
https://github.com/Techofficer/prelauncher

This app allows your subscribers to receive prizes using a referral code based on the number of friends that sign up via the referral link shared from their social page.

By default this app uses Paperclip for uploading images for local storage.
The uploaded assets would be stored in the public/settings/...
Since I'm using Heroku, I've decided to configure Paperclip for AWS S3.

***controller:***

```
has_attached_file :cover_image,
                                :storage => :s3,
                                :s3_protocol => 'https',
                                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
                :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    validates_attachment :cover_image, :content_type => {:content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/}

    has_attached_file :additional_image,
                                :storage => :s3,
                                :s3_protocol => 'https',
                                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
                :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    validates_attachment :additional_image, :content_type => {:content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/}

    has_attached_file :facebook_image,
                                :storage => :s3,
                                :s3_protocol => 'https',
                                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
                :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    validates_attachment :facebook_image, :content_type => {:content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/}
```

Whenever I would upload a Facebook share photo from the admin console settings, the following appears in my Rails logs:

```
[AWS S3 404 0.059285 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"MY_BUCKET_NAME",:key=>"settings/facebook_images/000/000/001/original/fb_cover.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key
```

When I look into my AWS console, the file has indeed been uploaded to the path stated above:
`settings/facebook_images/000/000/001/original/fb_cover.jpg`

If I were to enter an email address to subscribe, select the Facebook sharing button, I would be redirected to the Share on Facebook page, however the image that should be shared is blank. The blank image should be the image that was uploaded to my AWS S3.

[image]

The logs below are shown whenever I click the Facebook social sharing icon.

```
2015-12-21T15:10:01.920124+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/https://s3.amazonaws.com/[MY_BUCKET_NAME]/settings/facebook_images/000/000/001/original/fb_cover.jpg?1450673098" for [MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE] at 2015-12-21 15:10:01 +0000
2015-12-21T15:10:01.922540+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-21T15:10:01.922544+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/https:/s3.amazonaws.com/[MY_BUCKET_NAME]/settings/facebook_images/000/000/001/original/fb_cover.jpg"):
```

Below are my configs:

`Gemfile (snippet)
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "paperclip"
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

***enviroments/production.rb:***
`config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`

***routes:***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  resources :prizes, except: :show
  resources :settings, only: [:create, :update, :index]

  resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :show, :destroy] do
    resources :shares, only: [] do
      collection do 
        get "/" => "shares#create"
      end
    end
  end

  root "users#new"
  get "privacy" => "pages#privacy"

end
```

If I were to not use AWS S3 and instead use the app Paperclip local storage defaults, the Share on Facebook would display just fine. Reason for using AWS is Heroku doesn't play nice with uploaded media.

Please know that I do have the option of uploading background images which displays fine on the app. It's just I'm having issues getting the Facebook social sharing image to display on Share on Facebook page.

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) show for the URL you're sharing? Is Facebook able to see the meta tags and image associated with the URL you're sharing correctly?

Comment: When I enter the URL I receive `Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own.`. Please know that if I were to use the `Paperclip` local storage default settings, the Facebook sharing image display on my FB page just fine. If I were to use the AWS S3 settings, it does not. Also the AWS S3 uploads photos just fine and the view/download permissions are set accordingly for public viewing.